# Flutter Switch widget does not work if created inside initState()

Tags: dart, widget, flutter

I am trying to create a Switch widget add it to a List of widgets inside the initState and then add this list to the children property of a Column in the build method. The app runs successfully and the Switch widget does show but clicking it does not change it as if it is not working. I have tried making the same widget inside the build method and the Switch works as expected.

I have added some comments in the _onClicked which I have assigned to the onChanged property of the Switch widget that show the flow of the value property.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: App(),
  ));
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  AppState createState() => new AppState();
}

class AppState extends State<App> {

  List<Widget> widgetList = new List<Widget>();
  bool _value = false;

  void _onClicked(bool value) {
    print(_value); // prints false the first time and true for the rest
    setState(() {
      _value = value;
    });
    print(_value); // Always prints true
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    Switch myWidget = new Switch(value: _value, onChanged: _onClicked);
    widgetList.add(myWidget);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('My AppBar'),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
        child: new Center(
          child: new Column(children: widgetList),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `initState` is to initialize the state, not widgets. `build` is to create widgets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`initState` is to initialize the state, not widgets. `build` is to create widgets.

There reason it fails is because the widgets needs to be rebuilt when the value changes (when you call `setState`), but it isn't because when `build()` is called, the previously (in `initState`) created widget is reused.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> widgetList = [];
    Switch myWidget = new Switch(value: _value, onChanged: _onClicked);
    widgetList.add(myWidget);

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('My AppBar'),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
        child: new Center(
          child: new Column(children: widgetList),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So what would be the best way to initialize a Switch or a couple of Switch widgets and overcome this problem? Is it a good practice to set keys to the created Switches and then update the appropriate value of the list on _onClicked?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. Just use the same code you have in `initState` but execute it only from `build`, by either moving it to `build` directly or to a method called by `build` only.

Comment: Moving the initState code to build would make a new Switch get added to the list in each state change. That is why I need some way of initialization. What I am trying to achieve is add and remove Switches on runtime if that helps.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to update that part. See the first line I added to build. It seems you still stick with the idea that you build widgets outside `build()`. You shouldn't do that.

Comment: Thanks for making it clear. So if I were to need to add another Switch widget at runtime I am gonna need to add a counter that gets incremented every time the user adds a new switch and then make a loop and build all necessary Switches inside `build()` itself.

Comment: Exactly. . . . .. .